# MongoError: $each term takes only $slice (and optionally $sort) as complements

Tags: mongodb, meteor, minimongo

I am making a radio automation app that stores it's playlists in a mongoDB.  Each document in the `playlists` collection looks something like this:

```
{
  'name': 'My cool playlist',
  'items': [
    {'fileID': 'Cr4tT47K4EfJGQzfg'},
    {'fileID': 'Cr4tT49K4EfJGxffg'},
    {'fileID': 'Cr4tT49KH7EfJGQzfg'},
    {'fileID': '45otT49K4EfJGQzfg'},
    {'fileID': 'Dr4tT49K4EfJGQzfg'},
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to use this query to insert an array of elements at a certain position:

```
$push: {'items': { $each: insertArray, $position: insertPos}}
```

(`insertArray` is the array of elements to insert.  `insertPos` is the variable containing the position at which I want the array to be inserted.)

MongoDB gives me this error: `MongoError: $each term takes only $slice (and optionally $sort) as complements`

I'm using mongoDB version 2.4.9 from Meteor 0.9.2.2.  In other words, I'm actually querying minimongo which emulates mongoDB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query won't work with MongoDB 2.4.9 because the [`$position`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/#up._S_position) operator was added in 2.6.